# PHP Dropdown populating years - how to select current year

Tags: php

I have this PHP Code that is populating values in a SELECT box for the previous 10 years and the next 10 years.

```
<select name="fromYear"';
   $starting_year  =date('Y', strtotime('-10 year'));
   $ending_year = date('Y', strtotime('+10 year'));

    for($starting_year; $starting_year <= $ending_year; $starting_year++) {
 echo '<option value="'.$starting_year.'">'.$starting_year.'</option>';
  }             
 echo '<select>
```

how can I make it automatically select the current year?

Comment: You can obtain the current year with `$curyear = date('Y')` so just check for that inside your loop.

Answer (score 9):

```
<select name="fromYear"';
 $starting_year  =date('Y', strtotime('-10 year'));
 $ending_year = date('Y', strtotime('+10 year'));
 $current_year = date('Y');
 for($starting_year; $starting_year <= $ending_year; $starting_year++) {
     echo '<option value="'.$starting_year.'"';
     if( $starting_year ==  $current_year ) {
            echo ' selected="selected"';
     }
     echo ' >'.$starting_year.'</option>';
 }               
 echo '<select>';
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
//get the current year
$Startyear=date('Y');
$endYear=$Startyear-10;

// set start and end year range i.e the start year
$yearArray = range($Startyear,$endYear);
?>
<!-- here you displaying the dropdown list -->
<select name="year">
    <option value="">Select Year</option>
    <?php
    foreach ($yearArray as $year) {
        // this allows you to select a particular year
        $selected = ($year == $Startyear) ? 'selected' : '';
        echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$year.'">'.$year.'</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: it would be better to set the `selected` as defined by specification: `$selected = ($year == $Startyear) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';` otherwise browsers may ignore the selected state.

Answer (score 2):

Check the year with current year and make it selected.

```
for($starting_year; $starting_year <= $ending_year; $starting_year++) {
    if($starting_year == date('Y')) {
        echo '<option value="'.$starting_year.'" selected="selected">'.$starting_year.'</option>';
    } else {
        echo '<option value="'.$starting_year.'">'.$starting_year.'</option>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your echo to:

```
 echo '<option'.($starting_year == date('Y')) ? "selected=\"selected\"" : "".' value="'.$starting_year.'">'.$starting_year.'</option>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for($starting_year; $starting_year <= $ending_year; $starting_year++) {
    if($starting_year == date('Y')){
        echo '<option selected=selected value="'.$starting_year.'">'.$starting_year.'</option>';
    }else{
        echo '<option value="'.$starting_year.'">'.$starting_year.'</option>';
    }
}
```

Please use the code above for loop, instead of yours.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<select name="fromYear">';
$cur_year = date('Y');
for($year = ($cur_year-10); $year <= ($cur_year+10); $year++) {
    if ($year == $cur_year) {
        echo '<option value="'.$year.'" selected="selected">'.$year.'</option>';
    } else {
        echo '<option value="'.$year.'">'.$year.'</option>';
    }
}               
echo '<select>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [selected attributed](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp)

```
$starting_year  =date('Y', strtotime('-10 year'));
$ending_year = date('Y', strtotime('+10 year'));
for($starting_year; $starting_year <= $ending_year; $starting_year++) {
   if(date('Y')==$starting_year) { //is the loop currently processing this year?
      $selected='selected'; //if so, save the word "selected" into a variable
   } else {  
      $selected='' ; //otherwise, ensure the variable is empty
   }
   //then include the variable inside the option element
   echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$starting_year.'">'.$starting_year.'</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for($starting_year; $starting_year <= $ending_year; $starting_year++) { 
 echo '<option value="'.$starting_year.'"'. if(starting_year == date('Y')) echo "selected"  .'>'.$starting_year.'</option>';   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**echo '<select name="fromYear">';
$starting_year  =date('Y', strtotime('-10 year'));
   $ending_year = date('Y', strtotime('+10 year'));
   $current_year = $starting_year+10;
   echo"<option value='$current_year'>$current_year</option>";
    for($starting_year; $starting_year <= $ending_year; $starting_year++) {
 echo '<option value="'.$starting_year.'">'.$starting_year.'</option>';
  } 
echo '<select>';**
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).