# Why the current year is not selected?

Tags: php, html

```
<select name="year"><?=ddY()?></select>  


function ddY(){
        for($i=1900;$i<=date('Y');$i++)
        $arr[] = $i;
        $arr = array_reverse($arr);
        foreach($arr as $year){ 
         if($year == date('Y')) {
         echo '<option value="'.$year.'" selected="selected">'.$year.'</option>';

         } else {
            echo '<option value="'.$year.'">'.$year.'</option>';
        }



        //echo'<option value="'.$year.'">'.$year.'</option>'; 
    } 
    }
```

dropdown is populated fine, but the current year is not selected.

Comment: `<option value="2013" selected="selected">2013</option>` for me. What exactly issue?

Comment: As a side note: You could also go backwards and avoid the second foreach loop like: `for ($i = date('y'); $i >= 1990; --$i) {}`.

Comment: Did you tried looking ? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320244/php-dropdown-populating-years-how-to-select-current-year

Comment: @AmalMurali, is `2013` selected ? Cant' believe. I tried hundred of times, clearing cache...

Comment: works for me: http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/mtd-7q4, click run and it will show you what happens when it runs.

Comment: @SunSky If you are trying to run your code "as shown" on screen, it will generate an error to "undefined function" as in `Call to undefined function ddY()`. Wrap your function inside `<?php // function etc. ?>` and it will work. That is what I suspect is happening, if you think it's not working for you.

Comment: On a side note, please don't run `date('Y')` all the time. Save it to a variable. The year won't change during the `0.002` seconds that the script runs and right now you're running it a total of `226` times (once for every iteration in your first loop, once for every iteration in your second loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you are trying to run your code "as shown" on screen as per your posted question and it will generate an error to "undefined function" as in `Call to undefined function ddY()`.

Wrap your function inside `<?php // function etc. ?>` and it will work. That is what I suspect is happening.

#### Reformatted code: (tested)

```
<select name="year"><?=ddY()?></select>  

<?php

function ddY(){
        for($i=1900;$i<=date('Y');$i++)
        $arr[] = $i;
        $arr = array_reverse($arr);
        foreach($arr as $year){ 
         if($year == date('Y')) {
         echo '<option value="'.$year.'" selected="selected">'.$year.'</option>';

         } else {
            echo '<option value="'.$year.'">'.$year.'</option>';
        }



        //echo'<option value="'.$year.'">'.$year.'</option>'; 
    } 
    }

?>
```

#### Output:

```
<select name="year">
<option value="2013" selected="selected">2013</option>
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2011">2011</option>
<option value="2010">2010</option>
<option value="2009">2009</option>
<option value="2008">2008</option>
<option value="2007">2007</option>
```

#### etc.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get a selected value is:
I am using the non-concatenated method:

```
<option value="<?php echo $year; ?>" <?php if($year == date('Y')) { echo "selected"; } ?>  ><?php echo $year; ?></option>
```

Also check your variables that either they are providing you the appropriate values or not.

Answer (score 1):

It should work completely fine. **This is not an answer - just a suggestion for a rewrite of your two loops**:

```
<select name="year">
    <?php
        $currentYear = (int)date('Y');
        for ($i = $currentYear; $i >= 1900; $i--) {
            echo '<option value="' . $i . '"' . ($i == $currentYear ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . '>' . $i . '</option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.org/PGgBaoTl).

Output:

```
<select name="year">
    <option value="2013" selected="selected">2013</option>
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    <option value="2011">2011</option>
    <option value="2010">2010</option>
    ...
    <option value="1903">1903</option>
    <option value="1902">1902</option>
    <option value="1901">1901</option>
    <option value="1900">1900</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is code:

```
<option value="<?php echo $year; ?>" <?php echo ($year == date('Y')) ? "selected":""; } ?>  ><?php echo $year; ?></option>
```